# dojox.form.CheckedMultiSelect load async store and default selet all after loaded

Tags: dojo, dijit.form

http://download.dojotoolkit.org/release-1.12.2/dojo-release-1.12.2/dojox/form/tests/test_CheckedMultiSelectNonDropDown.html

from the following example, I know how to load a asycn read store to the CheckedMultiSelect, so how to force it check all the options after the async store is fully loaded???

```
<script>
readStore = new ItemFileReadStore({data:lang.clone(data)});
</script>
<select data-dojo-id="ms4" multiple="true" size="5" name="ms4" store="readStore" data-dojo-type="dojox.form.CheckedMultiSelect"></select>
```

Comment: There's opened [ticket](https://bugs.dojotoolkit.org/ticket/18947) for adding method selectAll (you can see there how to extend CheckedMultiSelect module and invoke this function in `onSetStore`[method](https://dojotoolkit.org/api/?qs=1.10/dojox/form/CheckedMultiSelect#onSetStore) - see only description, example is incorrect).

Comment: thank you so much, onSetStore is the solution!!!